# Can't log into localhost:8000/admin ... ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, django, web, localhost

I'm still pretty new to this web dev. I have been having trouble accessing the django admin site. I'm able to do `localhost:8000` just fine.

If I do `localhost:8000/admin`, I'm directed to the admin login page. I have already created id/pw through `createsuperuser`.

Anyway, once I type in my id and pw, I noticed my dev server (localhost or 127.0.0.1) terminates and the login page will throw me an error saying "this site can't be reached" with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I've tried turning off my internet/firewall, but it still gave me the same result. 
I would greatly appreciate your help. I've been having so much trouble with this because I can't access the django admin site...

(i'm using macOS Catalina, if that's any useful. Also I'm just following the basic Django tutorials, so i'm not using anything like gunicorn or nginx either.
)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited info:

1. Try to access `127.0.0.1:8000/admin` instead of `localhost:8000/admin`.
2. In django's settings set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` (**NOTE:** This is only for development).
3. Check if something else is not already runnning on that port. You can use the following command on Mac `lsof -Pn -i4 | grep -i "listen"`.

Comment: I have already tried both 127.0.0.1:8000/admin and localhost:8000/admin. Neither works. I have also added '*' for ALLOWED_HOSTS. Still nothing. I have also used the command you gave, and there's no other program that uses port 8000 other than my localhost

Comment: What python and django versions are you using? I had a similar issue when using django 3.0 and python 3.7.0. You can read more about the issue here - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31092.
The solution is to upgrade your python to the latest 3.7.* version.

Comment: oh wow... yeah my python version is 3.7.0 and django 3.0... I'll try upgrading my python version and see if things will work. (crossing-fingers)

Comment: Thanks you @TeodorIvanov I was able make it work after upgrading python version to 3.8!!!!!!!! such a savior! :)

Comment: Happy to help :)